# How to Save File in storage folder with Original name?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to store an uploaded file with its original client name in the storage folder. What do I need to add or change in my code?Any help or recommendation will be greatly appreciated

Here my Controller

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $path = "dev/table/".$input['id']."";
    $originalName = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file = $request->file;
    
    
    Storage::disk('local')->put($path . '/' . $originalName, $request->file);
}
```

Edit: I know how to get the originalClientName. the problem is storing the file in the folder using the original name, not the hash name. It doesn't store in the file in the original it makes a new folder instead here is the output `"dev/table/101/Capture1.PNG/xtZ9iFoJMoLrLaPDDPvc4DMJEXkRL3R4qWOionMC.png"` what I trying to get is `"dev/table/101/Capture1.PNG"`

I have tried to use `StoreAs` Or `putFileAs` but the method is undefined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to figure out how to store it with a custom name, for those who want to know how to do it here is the code

```
$id = $input['id'];
$originalName = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
$path = "dev/table/$id/".$originalName;

Storage::disk('local')->put($path, file_get_contents($request->file));
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the original file name you can use this in your ControllerClass:
`$file = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();`

To get additional the extension you can use this Laravel Request Method:

`$ext = $request->file->getClientOriginalExtension();`

Then you can save with:

```
$fileName = $file.'.'.$ext;
$request->file->storeAs($path, $fileName);
// or 
Storage::disk('local')->put($path . '/' . $fileName , $request->file);
```

Comment: I cant use StoreAs function cause I'm gonna store it on another server, not locally, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @MamaWin You can also use `Storage::disk('local')->put($path, $fileName);`Like in your question. But pass the $fileName to it.

Comment: I Tried but it failed with the message `Filename invalid", exception: "ErrorException",…}`

Comment: @MamaWin Thank you for feedback. My mistake. put requires the full path and the file object. i fixed. ;-)

Comment: in the `Storage::disk('local')->put($path . '/' . $request->file);` it expected 2 argument but only 1 founded.

Comment: @MamaWin   Oh no! today is not my day. i have changed it!

Comment: it doesn't store in the file in the original it makes a new folder instead here is the output `"dev/table/101/Capture1.PNG/xtZ9iFoJMoLrLaPDDPvc4DMJEXkRL3R4qWOionMC.png"` what I trying to get is `"dev/table/101/Capture1.PNG`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242805/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-mamawin).

Answer (score 2):

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
    
    $originalName = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension = $request->file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $path = "dev/table/" . $input['id'] . "/" . $originalName . "." . $extension;

    $file = $request->file;
    
    
    Storage::disk('local')->put($path, $file);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't store the file's original name, it only creates a new folder with the original client name.I'm looking for it to change the File Name.But thanks for the sugestion.

Comment: It'll create a folder with `$input['id']` and place the file with it's original name inside it.

Comment: The output is `"dev/table/101/Capture1.PNG.PNG/QiETqT111NCkBX42DRSmc79R7qRCOwdRlRUNA1xy.png"` what I'm trying to get `"dev/table/101/Capture1.PNG"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can save files using storage with the default name using `putFileAs` function instead of `put` which allow take third param as a file name

```
$path = "dev/table/101/";
$originalName = request()->file->getClientOriginalName();
$image = request()->file;

Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs($path, $image, $originalName);
```

**Update**

You can do something like this with put,

```
 Storage::disk('local')->put($path.$originalName, file_get_contents($image));
```

Comment: `putFileAs` method is undefined

Comment: what;s your laravel version ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i have figure it out using `put`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to manage like this;

```
  $insurance = $request->file('insurance_papers');
                $insuranceExtention = $insurance->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = "public/files/" . $carrier->id . "/insurance_papers." . $insuranceExtention;
                Storage::disk('local')->put($path, file_get_contents($insurance));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, this is work for me

```
if ($request->hasFile('attachment')) {
     $image      = $request->file('attachment');
     $imageName  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $path       = "foldername/".$imageName;

     Storage::disk('public')->put($path, file_get_contents($image));                
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).